# Make Custom NavigationViewController with My MapView and in my viewController using Mapbox in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I want to integrate `Mapbox` navigation in iOS, I can easily navigation my path from `Mapbox` we can use below code

```
let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: self.directionsRoute!)  
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But the problem is NavigationViewController is present and mapView generate second time.I want to use my customise map in NavigationViewController and use there delegate method.

So please help me for how i correct my way to use things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add some more code?

Comment: **NavigationViewController is present and mapView generate second time** what is happing exactly.